# Can we create List in another site collection using CSOM?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, client-object-model, csom

I have a very simple scenario. I am using SharePoint Online
I have 2 site collections SC1 and SC2. Now i am executing a JavaScript function in SC1 and am trying to create a list in SC2 in a sub-site using CSOM.
First question is, Is it possible? second question is How?

Please note that I have tried using the REST approach which works but that has a drawback that you have to make multiple ajax calls to create columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not provided whole code but you can call cross site connection using JavaScript. Take a reference from below code:

```
var crossSiteContext = new SP.ClientContext("http://url-of-another-siteCollection/");
var crossSiteWeb = crossSiteContext.get_web();
crossSiteContext.load(crossSiteWeb);
crossSiteContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){

    var listCreationInfo = new SP.ListCreationInformation();  
    listCreationInfo.set_title('ListName');  
    listCreationInfo.set_templateType(SP.ListTemplateType.announcements);  
    this.oList = crossSiteWeb.get_lists().add(listCreationInfo);  
    crossSiteContext.load(oList);   

},function(sender,args){ alert(args.get_message()); });
```

You can get reference from this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201(v=office.15).aspx#BasicOps_SPListItemTasks) for JavaScript code in SharePoint.

Comment: Its giving me an error : SP.ClientContext is not a constructor anything i am missing?

Comment: Thank you it worked. The error was because of something else.

Answer (score 1):

For **SharePoint Online / Office 365**, you can use JSOM to make cross-site collection calls as long as the site collections are all in the **same tenant**.

---

There are only two scenarios where you can make cross-site collection calls using the JavaScript Object Model in a **SharePoint on-premises farm**:

1. Both site collections are located in the same web application and none of them is a host-named site collection. Basically the domain of both site collections needs to be the same.
2. You make the calls from within a SharePoint-Hosted Add-in (aka App) and use [**the web proxy**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179895.aspx) to access data from any site collections, regardless in which web application they are hosted. With this you can actually make calls to non-SharePoint resources (e.g. public web services). In SP-hosted Add-ins you can also use [**the cross-domain library**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179927.aspx) to achieve the same results I described above at point 1.

---

Regarding how to do this, see Dikesh's answer. The important bit is `new SP.ClientContext("http://url-of-another-siteCollection/");` where you specify the URL of the site located in the site collection where you're trying to create the list.

Comment: so in Sharepoint Online terms it should be in the same tenant or under the same account?

Comment: A tenant in SharePoint online is basically equivalent to a web application in SharePoint on-premise farm, as far as JSOM is concerned. I will update my answer.